# Which type of In App Purchase to be used for iOS app where a content purchased can be later removed and then may be added again

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to create some In App Purchases for my app and thus need to ask some questions regarding it to survive from review rejection. I have read the App Review Guidelines and the documentations regarding In App Purchase(IAP) but as per the requirements of the app I am in dilemma which type (consumable, non consumable,auto renewable subscription) of IAP should I use so that I can save my app from future review rejection. Please review the **detailed description below** and suggest me your expert advices, thanks:

The app I am developing is an institution app which will list the institution members associated to each post. I have the Bio Details (detailed data) of some members (like his/her birthday,Educational qualifications, Previous Posts, etc )which I want to make available as IAP, so I have to create two kind of In App purchases in the app as mentioned below to have:

1) Separate Bio Details IAP for each member (allows the user to select and purchase Bio details of selected members only to unlock his Bio) 
1) Birthday Reminders Service (a yearly subscription that will display a local notification on the day of a member’s birthday). Service must be renewed yearly on the day and month of the first purchase.

**Thus my questions are:**

**Quest 1)** For implementing first IAP i.e **‘Bio Details for each member’** which **type of IAP should I use** i.e **Consumable or Non Consumable**? As there is a **use case** that suppose a user has purchased an IAP for Bio Details of **Member X which is currently assigned to some institution post but later on that member is not serving the institution and thus will be removed from the app and his Bio details will no longer be visible in the app unless he joins the institution again later**. Should I go with non - consumable to show the Bio details till the member is in the institution or do I have to use Consumable IAP in this case ?Please suggest.

**Quest 2)** For **‘Birthday Reminders Service’** IAP I’ll be using the **Local Notifications** to generate the reminders.Firstly, **can I use this service as IAP ?** Secondly, as this needs to be an yearly subscription **can I use Auto Renewable Subscription type of IAP for this ?**(as Apple says Auto renewable service should provide periodically dynamic content and some says its for Newstand only) If yes please guide how to implement it. I know that I can use non renewable subscription but I can’t provide user login on this app. **Also can I use Consumable IAP for this case** in which it will be available as 1 year IAP product on single device ?

Thanks for reading this and your support. Kindly let me know if I am unable to make my point clear. I really need your help and support so that I can move ahead on right path and save myself from future rejections of app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non consumable in first instance. It doesn't consume. Once the user has purchased info on certain member x that info when valid will always be available.

And non auto renewing for the second instance

Comment: thanks for your answers. Suppose if I go with Non Consumable IAP for first instance then I hope Apple or users will not have any issues if the invalid info is removed even if some user's have purchased that IAP.

Comment: Well why would the user require the info if no longer applicable? They paid for what you gave them. If possible consider leaving member X in the app but having a label saying no longer applicable or similar?